# How should I present paired sample test results?

Tags: t-test, paired-comparisons

I conducted a paired sample t-test on pre and post questionnaire results. What should I be reporting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think we can give you any concrete help because the style of reporting statistics depends on the types of audience and channel, none of which the question has indicated. Try perform an [online search](https://www.google.com/search?q=paried+sample+t-test+how+to+report) for some inspirations.

Generally, some usual candidates are the research questions, means and standard deviations of the two groups, difference in means and the associated confidence interval, sample size, *t*-statistics, and the associated *p*-value.

Comment: Hi  ,thanks. Had already done that, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything out. I hadn't added the confidence interval info -will pop that in thanks.